# How to convert Tue Jun 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) into date format in vue js

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am using vue2-datepicker but i can't save date into database because the date format binded as Tue Jun 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
How can i solve this?

my code is

```
 <date-picker 
      type="date"
      :lang="lang" 
      v-model="form.join_date" 
      >
 </date-picker>
```

but console.log(this.form.join_date) is Tue Jun 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

How can i get date like '2019-06-18'

Anyone can help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for your quick support.
I get it fixed by 
 <date-picker 
                            v-model="form.join_date" 
                            valueType="format" 
                            lang="en" >
                        </date-picker>

Answer (score 1):

There is an attribute called `value-type` that would let you bind a string with a specific format instead of a Date object. Based on [their examples](https://mengxiong10.github.io/vue2-datepicker/demo/index.html), I believe it would be something like this:

```
<date-picker 
      value-type="format"
      format="YYYY-MM-dd"
      :lang="lang" 
      v-model="stringValue">
</date-picker>
```

See here: https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker#value-type

Comment: thanks for your support, i get it fixed by
 <date-picker 
                            v-model="form.join_date" 
                            valueType="format" 
                            lang="en" >
                        </date-picker>

Comment: @JobRajan No problem! If my answer helped you out, would you mind marking it accepted by clicking that check mark next to it?